# Can I write this .NET foreach loop shorter?

Tags: c#, .net

I think there is a shorter way of writing this `foreach` loop that creates a deep copy of a `SortedDictionary<string, object>`.  Note that `object` is just a place holder, I'm really using some other reference type there.  Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> entry in sortedDictionary)
{
    this.mSortedDictionary.Add(entry.Key, new object());
}
```

Comment: Well I suppose you could write it with 0 lines instead of 1, but that probably wouldn't help very much...

Comment: Shorter than one line?  You are worrying about the wrong things.

Comment: you could change your variable names to `a`, `b`, etc. and save a few characters--doesn't mean you should.  What are you after?  Performance--a `for` loop is faster than `foreach`, but loses the transactional aspect of running over an enumerator

Comment: Are you trying to use the `mSortedDictionary` as set?

Comment: Did you mean to say more efficient rather than shorter?

Comment: I just wanted to be able to win at code golf with C#!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whats the point, this is perfectly short.

And for the record, you can make an extension method for Dictioary (or IDictioary) that does this. From then on, you can call the extension method on any dictioary.

Answer (score 4):

```
mSortedDictionary = sortedDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => new Object());
```

Comment: ...this is not equivalent, the original code may be adding the items to an existing dictionary...

Comment: Please no.. lambdas just make someone else's job harder when they have to read your code two months down the line ;-)

Answer (score 2):

One of the rules of thumb of programming: in every other loop, there is a catamorphism (also called `fold`, `reduce`, `inject:into:` or `inject`) waiting to get out. This is also the case here. Thankfully, one of the LINQ operators provides a catamorphism for us, which Microsoft calls `Aggregate`:

```
sortedDictionary.Aggregate(mSortedDictionary, (d, e) => {
    d.Add(e.Key, Transform(e.Value)); return d; });
```

Note: this could be further simplified by using the K combinator and a destructuring bind. Unfortunately, I couldn't find the K combinator in the BCL, although I'm pretty sure it *has* to be there somewhere. (If anybody knows, please tell me.)

For the purpose of this example, I'm going to provide my own K combinator and I'm going to call it `Tap` for no other reason than that's what it's called in Ruby:

```
public static T Tap<T>(this T o, Action<T> f) { f(o); return o; }
```

That's literally all there is to it. (Well, at least if you ignore thread-safety and exceptions …)

Using the K combinator, we arrive at this:

```
sortedDictionary.Aggregate(mSortedDictionary, (d, e) => d.Tap(dd =>
    dd.Add(e.Key, Transform(e.Value))));
```

Which is much easier on the eye.

Unfortunately, we cannot add destructuring bind ourselves, but if C# *did* support destructuring bind, it would look more like this:

```
sortedDictionary.Aggregate(mSortedDictionary, (d, {k, v}) => d.Tap(dd =>
    dd.Add(k, Transform(v))));
```

[Note: in this example, I use object initializer syntax for destructuring bind.]

For example, in Ruby, which *does* have both destructuring bind and the K combinator, it would look like this:

```
sorted_dictionary.reduce(m_sorted_dictionary) {|d, (k, v)|
  d.tap {|d| d[k] = transform(v) }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Grab the nVentive Umbrella Extensions library (http://umbrella.codeplex.com) and:

```
sortedDictionary.ForEach(s => mSortedDictionary.Add(s, new object()));
```

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach( string key in sortedDictionary.Keys ) {
   mSortedDictionary.Add(key, new object());
}
```

Comment: The OP stated that the `new object()` line was just a placeholder, presumably for deep-copy of the object referenced by the original dictionary. Enumerating over keys does not solve the problem.

Comment: Of course it does, e.g.: mSortedDictionary.Add(key, sortedDictionary[key].Clone());.. but "presumably" indicates your interpretation of the question.